# Can anyone explain about "Formula Value" of v1 ,v2 ​ in PredictionValuesChange of Feature importance in CatBoost? what is Formula Value?

Tags: python, decision-tree, feature-selection, feature-engineering, catboost

what is Formula Value? -->  "Formula Value" of v1  ,v2 ​ in  PredictionValuesChange of Feature importance in CatBoost?

to find out what meaning of Formula Value ? calculate from what criteria?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just curious that what is Formula Value? how this value  come? what is criteria for calculation of Formula Value to put in V1 V2.  from --> https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/fstr#fstr__regular-feature-importance --> PredictionValuesChange --> Calculation principles  --> V1 V2  represent the formula value in the left and right leaves respectively.